# What are these plug-like cable endings called?

Tags: breadboard, components

I've been looking for things like the plugs displayed on these orange wires in this photo:

[image: mysterious item]

What are they called?  I imagine that this is a part that I could buy somewhere.

Comment: @TomWij, yes, in general comments like "thanks" are removed, but only if there is another reason to edit. Editing to just remove thanks is a bit ridiculous.

Comment: @TomWij, I saw your other changes, so I approved it, but since your edit comment had a question this seemed to be the best way to respond. Glad to see you visiting our neck of the woods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All they are are stiff peices of wire soldered to stranded Wire with a molded rubber case. 
you can buy them from [adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=33&products_id=153&zenid=8967f547ed39a32b68281ada555ae56e), also called bread-boarding cables, jumper cables, (premium) wire jumpers.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

OK, they are known as 'Jumper Wires'  Here is a link to some that SparkFun sells.  I'll bet that they can easily be located in different sizes, etc. elsewhere.

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9194

This page refers to them as 'leads' and gives some DIY instruction on making them stackable:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Stackable-Jump-leads-for-BreadBoards/

And again, for the DIY type person, on page 6 of this catalog is a crimp-style terminal.

http://www.molex.com/catalog/web_catalog/pdfs/C.pdf

Comment: you should be able to accept your own answer.

Comment: Yeah, I still have to wait another day.  =)

Comment: I knew there was a delay, but I thought I would check to make sure you knew you could.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Looks like jsolarski really does have the best answer though.  I mean, that is a very good resource that he pointed out. =)

Comment: @AR, more importantly, there was a picture.

Answer (score 2):

Patch cords?

Unless I'm missing something, functionally, they're the same as wires. I wouldn't bother with them and would just use solid-core 22ga wire for solderless breadboard.

Comment: solid core wires are great, but when there are a lot of them their inflexibility can be bothersome.  Also, if the ends get little bends in them they become even more trouble.  I like to stay focused on the task at hand and not have to fiddle with little details all of the time.

Comment: ok, cool -- I learned something new :-)

Answer (score 0):

Those look like single row breakaway headers, like these: http://rndwarehouse.com/breakaway-headers-1x40-straight-singlerow-extended-height-p-213.html?zenid=83og3qmqjb3g10obpv92sbavo7.  I've done this in the past as it's the cheapest way to get non-solid core jumper wires for breadboarding.

In order to make them, you get a 40 pin header like the one I linked to, and then *carefully* break them apart, either with clippers or two pairs of pliers.  You want to solder your stranded wire to the short end and then use shrink tube over the connection.  The long end plugs into your breadboard.

EDIT -- looking at the picture again, they aren't breakaway headers, but I would still recommend going that route if you're okay with a little soldering.